# Extracting multiple nested objects using Hooks and copying it to a new list to use data in React App/Redux using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

New to Stackoverflow and a Junior Dev who needs help pls.

We have built an application to manage Webforms. Users have multiple Accounts/Departments, and each account/department have multiple users and managers.

Upon completion of the form the user can email it directly to their manager(s) by selecting the manager in a compiled dropdown.

## Question:

The issue currently is by using fetchAccountDetails I can only extract one array of managers from a specific account at a time. I can not seem to get all managers for my users from all the accounts they belong to.

I want to extract all managers from all accounts for my current user and then list them in the dropdown.

### The Output I require:

The current user's Manager dropdown needs to have the managers from all Accounts listed. The Account managers details is inside the Account/${id} for each account. how can I extract the managers for each account referencing the accId as ref.

### lookupStore.js

```
const FETCH_USERS = "FETCH_USERS";
const SET_USERS = "SET_USERS";
const FETCH_ACCOUNTS = "FETCH_ACCOUNT_DETAILS";
const SET_ACCOUNTS = "SET_ACCOUNT_DETAILS";


const initialState = { users: [], accounts: [],  accountDetails: [] };
export const actionCreators = {
    setUsers: data => ({ type: SET_USERS, payload: data }),
    setAccountDetails: data => ({ type: SET_ACCOUNT_DETAILS, payload: data })
};
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USERS: {
            return {
                ...state, users: [...action.payload.users]
            };
        }
        case FETCH_ACCOUNTS: {
            return {
                ...state, accounts: [...action.payload.accounts]
            };
        }
        case FETCH_ACCOUNT_DETAILS: {
            return {
                ...state, accountDetails: [...action.payload.accountDetails]
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const fetchUsers = (success, failure) => apiAction({
    url: "Users",
    onSuccess: success,
    onFailure: failure,
    label: FETCH_USERS
});

export const fetchAccountDetails = (id, success, failure) => apiAction({
    url: `Accounts/${id}`,
    onSuccess: success,
    onFailure: failure,
    label: FETCH_ACCOUNT_DETAILS
});
```

### myWebform.js

```
    import { actionCreators, fetchAccounts, fetchUsers, fetchAccounts, fetchAccountDetails } from '../../store/lookupStore';

    function WebForms(props) {
    
        //pulling from fetchUsers in lookupStore all users
        const users = useSelector(state => state.lookups.users);
        const userId = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'); 
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(fetchUsers(
                (data) => dispatch(actionCreators.setUsers(data))
    
            )); 
            if (userId == null) {
                dispatch(push("/")); //re-log in if null id
            }
            else {
                dispatch(fetchAccounts(
                    (data) => {
                        dispatch(actionCreators.setAccounts(data));
                    }
                ));
                dispatch(fetchAccountDetails(userId,
                    (data) => {
                        dispatch(actionCreators.setAccountDetails(data));
                    }
                ));
            }
    
        }, [dispatch]);
    
        //filter by active users only 1 = active || 0 = deactivated
        const userList = users.filter(user => user.status == 1); //  status 0 is inactive users
        //Complete userlist split and flattened into accounts
        const userAcc = [];
            usersList.map((user) => {
                user.accounts.forEach((acc) => {
                    userAcc.push({
                        id: user.id,
                        name: user.displayName,
                        accId: acc.id,
                        accName: acc.name,
                        managers: acc.managers
                    });
                });
           });
        const groupId = userAcc.map(acc => acc.id);

    //List of managers to be in dropdown
const managersInGroup= currentUserGroup.map(approver => approver.approvers);

const [managersList, setManagersList] = useState([]);
const [managerId, setManagerId] = useState(0);
        // load all details
        function loadWebForm() {
            dispatch(fetchWebForm(props.match.params.id,
                (data) => {
                    setWebForm(data.webForm)
                    htmlImageAndCssMapper(data.webForm.html, activePage - 1).then(xhtml => {
                        setHtmlData(xhtml)
                    })
                    setWebFormName(data.webForm.name);
                    setManagerId(data.webForm.managerId);
    
                    //new code from MG
                    if (managersInGroup.length) {
                        setManagersList(managersInGroup[0]);
                    } else {
                        var manager = [];
                        manager.push(currentUser);
                        setManagersList(currentUser);
                    }
                }
            ))
            console.log("currentUser====>", currentUser) // output is equal to == json - users
            console.log("groupId====>", groupId)  // output : [2, 6]
            console.log("managersInGroup====>", managersInGroup)  //  output only gives me managers of the last listed Account for my user
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and welcome to the world of programming.  As written, there is no obvious question here and there is simply too much code to easily reproduce expected behavior. Try to boil your question down to a single problem statement with the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate the problem.  Also, this currently has nothing to do with C#, regardless of the backend you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have edited the question and reduced code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be passing in the userId in place of the accountId inside of the useEffect.

You'll want to loop through the data returned of the Accounts and for each of those fetch and dispatch saving the manager / account details.

In the reducer you'll then want to change it from

```
...state, accountDetails: [...action.payload.accountDetails]
```

to

```
...state, accountDetails: [...state.accountDetails, ...action.payload.accountDetails]
```

An additional note, you don't need to send the fetch functions to the dispatch. It's being handled by the success side.